# Protocol Buffers NET to serialize a SortedDictionary<CustomTKey, CustomTValue>?

Tags: c#, collections, protobuf-net

Are there any known issues when using ProtoBuf.NET with a SortedDictionary? Specifically, we're using a `SortedDictionary<CustomTKey, CustomTValue>` (with the appropriate `IComparer<CustomTKey>` implementation but that's probably unrelated to ProtoBuf.NET's focus)

It's passing some basic tests at our end but wanted to know if there were any known issues or concerns to watch out for.

If it works, does the working extend in a general manner to other strongly types collection classes in the BCL (eg: Dictionary, SortedList etc)? I know for sure it works very well with `List`s!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf-net tries to avoid coding to any *specific* collection types, and instead tries to detect some key *patterns*; in particular, anything that looks like `IList`, `ICollection<T>`, or even just a custom iterator and `Add(Foo)`, where the `GetEnumerator()` returns an iterator where the `.Current` is of type `Foo`.

`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, which is what protobuf-net detects and uses; so the library treats it simply as a collection of key-value-pairs, calling `.Add` etc. `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is treated again by pattern logic as an "auto tuple": it has a constructor that takes all of the public members, so it maps them up in that order (the constructor is `KeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)`, so `.Key` is mapped as field 1, and `.Value` is mapped as field 2). Putting this together, protobuf-net maps:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo
{
    private readonly SortedDictionary<string, int> items =
        new SortedDictionary<string, int>(
        StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    SortedDictionary<string, int> Items { get {  return items; } }
}
```

via the schema (verifiable via `Serializer.GetProto<Foo>()`):

```
message Foo {
   repeated KeyValuePair_String_Int32 Items = 1;
}
message KeyValuePair_String_Int32 {
   optional string Key = 1;
   optional int32 Value = 2;
}
```

So basically, it should work fine; the only thing to watch would be to ensure that any custom `IComparer<CustomTKey>` gets applied. I've done that above by only giving protobuf-net access to the *getter*, and performing the collection initiation inside our custom type - but you could also use a before-deserialization callback to do the same thing if you wanted to enable constructor-skipping.

Comment: does a "before-deserialization callback" belong in the parameterless constructor?

Comment: @mcmillab not usually; a callback method is a method of known   signature, typically annotated via an interface or attribute; in the case of protobuf-net, it is an attribute; `[ProtoBeforeDeserialization]`.